# Force file download AND show a new page

Tags: php, download

I have found numerous examples on forcing he download of a file with PHP, but none of them show how to do this from a new page (e.g. a thank you for downloading page, with a button to start download if it didn't start already). When ever I use the header attachment method it just downloads the file whilst leaving the browser on the page I was on when I click the link.

I want to be able to show a new page and automatically start the download.  How do I do this with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by meta refresh on the "Thank you page" that you want where `5` is in seconds, change it to be a longer delay if you want.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=/download.php">
```

Then your download script where you're pointing at `URL=/download.php` should do the force download to what ever file it needs to serve.

Comment: This method is better as it doesn't rely on JS support.